# How to deal with large iterations of permutations efficently?

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, data-structures, permutation

How to solve problem like this efficently
problem
A array of range(1<s<e<10^9)  with target value K range(10^6) need to find no of pairs whose sum are even

```py
form itertools import product
counter=0
for i in product(array,repeat=k):
    if sum(i)%2==0
        counter+=1
print(counter)
```

As problem with above code is it always runs in **TLE** for long numbers any suggestion to solve this type of problems efficently?
sample input
range(1,10)k=2   `arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`
sample output
`{1,1},{1,3},{1,9}.......{10,8},{10,10}` there are total 50 pairs like this in the range(1,10)

Comment: Break into cases. For example, for `k=2` use `even + even = even`, `odd + odd = odd`, etc. Make a count of even and odd numbers in the list. Brute force (which you are trying to do) is utterly infeasible if `e` is close to `10^9` and `k` is greater than `2` (or even `1`)

Comment: When you say that you "need to find find no of pairs" do you mean that you need to find the number of `k-tuples`? In any event, the key will be to first fins the count of `even` and `odd` numbers in the range (which can be found with basic arithmetic given `s` and `e`).

Comment: Is this a homework or exam question? You can compute the result with simple algebra without enumerating anything.

Answer (score -1):

I would solve it like this:
instead of passing over each item in the list multiple times, i would index all distinct elements in the list assuming there are quite a few duplicates. for example, random distribution of ints 1 through 15, repeating 100 times. Then provided that list, I would place them in a dictionary and compare indexes:

if the key repeats more than 2 times, if it's odd or even it will sum to be even.
else, if the key sums with another key to be even, retrieve all of the indexes for both keys.

```
import secrets
from collections import defaultdict

x=0
randomlist = []
while x<100:
    y=secrets.choice(range(1,15))
    randomlist.append(y)
    x=x+1

ddict = defaultdict(list)
for i,r in enumerate(randomlist):
    ddict[r].append(i)
print(ddict)
for k,v in ddict.items():
    if len(v)>=2:
        print("even sum - " + str(k) + " : " + str(v))
    for i,j in ddict.items():
        if (k+i)%2==0 and k!=i:
            print("even sum - " + str(k) + " : " + str (i)+ " : " + str(v) + str(j))
```